# Abusing Excel VBA... to maintain data stored in a database

Tags: sql, mysql, vba, mvp

I need to build a little UI to allow easy maintenance of some data stored in a MySQL database, and the end user wants to do that in Excel (I know, I know).

The code I came up with comes pretty close to what I'd call Model-View-Presenter (MVP).

I can get my form shown like this:

```
set x = new CustomerGroupsPresenter
set x.Command = new SqlCommand
x.Show
```

Obviously this code uses the `SqlCommand` ADODB wrapper that I've written earlier (for VB6), reviewable [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46506/23788).

Here's the form's code-behind:

```
Public Event CloseCommand(ByVal sender As CustomerGroupsView)
Public Event EditCustomerGroupCommand(ByVal id As Long, ByVal description As String)
Public Event AddCustomerGroupCommand()
Public Event DeleteCustomerGroupCommand(ByVal id As Long)
Option Explicit

Private Sub AddCustomerGroupButton_Click()
    RaiseEvent AddCustomerGroupCommand
End Sub

Private Sub CloseButton_Click()
    RaiseEvent CloseCommand(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub CustomerGroupsList_Change()
    DeleteCustomerGroupButton.Enabled = Not (CustomerGroupsList.ListIndex = -1)
End Sub

Private Sub CustomerGroupsList_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    Dim selectedRecord() As String
    selectedRecord = Split(CustomerGroupsList.List(CustomerGroupsList.ListIndex), StringFormat("\t"))

    Dim id As Long
    id = CLng(selectedRecord(0))

    Dim description As String
    description = selectedRecord(1)

    RaiseEvent EditCustomerGroupCommand(id, description)

End Sub

Private Sub DeleteCustomerGroupButton_Click()

    Dim selectedRecord() As String
    selectedRecord = Split(CustomerGroupsList.List(CustomerGroupsList.ListIndex), StringFormat("\t"))

    Dim id As Long
    id = CLng(selectedRecord(0))

    RaiseEvent DeleteCustomerGroupCommand(id)

End Sub
```

..and the *Presenter* class:

```
Private cmd As SqlCommand
Private WithEvents vwCustomerGroups As CustomerGroupsView
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Command() As SqlCommand
    Set Command = cmd
End Property

Public Property Set Command(ByRef value As SqlCommand)
    Set cmd = value
End Property

Public Sub Show()

    Set vwCustomerGroups = New CustomerGroupsView
    RefreshCustomerGroups
    vwCustomerGroups.Show vbModal

End Sub

Private Function View() As CustomerGroupsView
    Set View = vwCustomerGroups
End Function

Private Sub RefreshCustomerGroups()

    vwCustomerGroups.CustomerGroupsList.Clear

    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT Id, Description FROM Planning.CustomerGroups ORDER BY Id;"

    Dim groups As SqlResult
    Set groups = cmd.QuickExecute(sql)
    groups.ValueSeparator = StringFormat("\t")

    Dim group As SqlResultRow
    For Each group In groups
        vwCustomerGroups.CustomerGroupsList.AddItem group.ToString
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub vwCustomerGroups_AddCustomerGroupCommand()

    Dim description As String
    description = InputBox("Please enter a description for the new CustomerGroup:", "Edit", "(new customer group)")

    If StrPtr(description) = 0 Or description = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    Dim sql As String
    sql = "INSERT INTO Planning.CustomerGroups (Description, DateInserted) VALUES (?, ?);"

    Dim success As Boolean
    success = cmd.QuickExecuteNonQuery(sql, description, Now)

    If Not success Then MsgBox "Insert operation failed!", vbExclamation, "Warning"
    RefreshCustomerGroups

End Sub

Private Sub vwCustomerGroups_CloseCommand(ByVal sender As CustomerGroupsView)
    sender.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub vwCustomerGroups_DeleteCustomerGroupCommand(ByVal id As Long)

    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Planning.Customers WHERE CustomerGroupId = ?;"

    Dim childRecords As Long
    childRecords = CLng(cmd.QuickSelectSingleValue(sql, id))

    If childRecords > 0 Then
        MsgBox StringFormat("This CustomerGroup has {0} customer(s) associated to it and cannot be deleted.", childRecords), vbExclamation, "FK Constraint violation!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If MsgBox(StringFormat("Delete CustomerGroup #{0}?\n(this cannot be undone!)", id), vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Please confirm") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    sql = "DELETE FROM Planning.CustomerGroups WHERE Id = ?;"

    Dim success As Boolean
    success = cmd.QuickExecuteNonQuery(sql, id)

    If Not success Then MsgBox "Delete operation failed!", vbExclamation, "Warning"
    RefreshCustomerGroups

End Sub

Private Sub vwCustomerGroups_EditCustomerGroupCommand(ByVal id As Long, ByVal description As String)

    Dim newDescription As String
    newDescription = InputBox(StringFormat("Please enter a new description for CustomerGroup ID#{0}:", id), "Edit", description)

    If StrPtr(newDescription) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim sql As String
    sql = "UPDATE Planning.CustomerGroups SET Description = ?, DateUpdated = ? WHERE Id = ?;"

    Dim success As Boolean
    success = cmd.QuickExecuteNonQuery(sql, newDescription, Now, id)

    If Not success Then MsgBox "Update operation failed!", vbExclamation, "Warning"
    RefreshCustomerGroups

End Sub
```

I feel like I could move the SQL outside the Presenter class and into some data service class.. but would that be overkill?

Besides the missing error-handling, what's there to say about this code?

Comment: Nevermind the `View()` function, I forgot to remove it... it's just a relic from a previous approach / dead code now.

Comment: It should also be noted that the MySQL backend somehow doesn't support FK's.

Comment: Also `SqlResultRow` implements an `IStringRepresentable` interface that exposes a `ToString` method - should I not declare `group as IStringRepresentable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

I wasn't going to review this, but I couldn't stop reading it again and again. So, here I am reviewing it. I'm going to go down line by line, but first let me address your question. Would creating a data service class be overkill? Right now, I think it would be. Overall this is a pretty clean implementation. Yes, the presenter is technically doing two things, but adding a data service just adds to the complexity. Add it when it makes sense to add it. YAGNI.

Another thing I would like to mention is that you're using a number of custom classes. Which is good. Developers should have a tool box. BUT.. the average VBA developer is not an actual developer. So, take into consideration who will be maintaining this after you've moved on. Will it be a business person who *thinks* they know how to program, or will it be a legitimate developer who has somehow been suckered into playing Mr. Maintainer for the project. (Let's face it, someone must have blackmailed him or her into it.) I think it makes a big difference on how much you rely on your toolbox that lets you program in a more C# type style.

Ok, on to the review...

#### Form's Code Behind

- First, I'm going to nit-pick about something that really doesn't matter, but drives me crazy. `Option Explicit` should be the very first thing in any module. I'm happy to see you use it, but move it to where it belongs.
- I think it is absolutely awesome that you're using custom object events. It's a highly under-utilized feature of the language. I really think you should go ahead and add a `cancel` parameter to all of these though. As a developer, I would want a way to bail out of Editing, Adding, and (especially) Deleting. Note that by using `ByRef` for the cancel parameter, we can "send" the cancel value back to the calling code so it can act appropriately if the event was canceled internally.

  ```
  Public Event CloseCommand(ByVal sender As CustomerGroupsView, Optional ByRef Cancel As Boolean = False)
  Public Event EditCustomerGroupCommand(ByVal id As Long, ByVal description As String, Optional ByRef Cancel As Boolean = False)
  Public Event AddCustomerGroupCommand(Optional ByRef Cancel As Boolean = False)
  Public Event DeleteCustomerGroupCommand(ByVal id As Long, Optional ByRef Cancel As Boolean = False)
  ```

#### Presenter

- Same deal. Move `Option Explicit` to the first line.
- Ditch the hungarian notation. You don't use it anywhere else, don't use it here. `vwCustomerGroups` is fine as just `customerGroups`. I do get why it was so tempting to do it though.
- `"\t"` could be a constant `TAB`, but not a big deal.
- **`vwCutstomerGroups_AddCustomerGroupCommand()`**

  - The inputbox code scrolls  off the screen. This would be a legitimate use of line continuations.

    ```
    Dim description As String
    description = InputBox("Please enter a description for the new CustomerGroup:", _
        "Edit" , "(new customer group)")
    ```
  - It's hard to know when to use a one line `If` statement. I think this one is ok, but there are others that aren't.
  - I like seeing your use of proper parameterized queries.
- **`vwCustomerGroups_DeleteCustomerGroupCommand`**

  - The message box code scrolls off my screen again. This time I'll offer an alternative way to utilize line continuations. I personally think this is a cleaner way to do it.

    ```
    MsgBox _
        Prompt:=StringFormat("This CustomerGroup has {0} customer(s) associated to it and cannot be deleted.", childRecords), _
        Buttons:=vbExclamation, _
        Title:="FK Constraint violation!"
    ```
  - I understand from chat that your RDBMS doesn't support foreign keys. You can fake foreign keys with a trigger if you choose to do so. Triggers are typically evil, but I think this would be an acceptable use of them. Your database should be enforcing the data integrity, not your application.
  - This is a heck of a line of code here. Not only does it scroll off of the screen, it's an if statement. This one is *not* ok to leave as a one liner.

    ```
    If MsgBox(StringFormat("Delete CustomerGroup #{0}?\n(this cannot be undone!)", id), vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Please confirm") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    ```