# Honey I shrunk the view

Tags: object-oriented, vba, mvp, layout

[Going down the rabbit hole](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/58348/23788), I wanted to be able to change the size of a form, and not have to worry about the layout of the controls.

[vba](/questions/tagged/vba) doesn't support user-resizeable forms, but forms still have a `Resize` *event* that fires when a form's size is *programmatically* changed.

I'm leveraging this event handler to set up my automatic layout, like this:

> ```
> Private Sub BindControlLayouts()
>
>     Dim backgroundImageLayout As New ControlLayout
>     backgroundImageLayout.Bind Me, BackgroundImage, AnchorAll
>
>     Dim closeButtonLayout As New ControlLayout
>     closeButtonLayout.Bind Me, CloseButton, BottomAnchor + RightAnchor
>
>     Dim itemsListLayout As New ControlLayout
>     itemsListLayout.Bind Me, ItemsList, AnchorAll
>
>     Dim addButtonLayout As New ControlLayout
>     addButtonLayout.Bind Me, AddButton, RightAnchor
>
>     Dim editButtonLayout As New ControlLayout
>     editButtonLayout.Bind Me, EditButton, RightAnchor
>
>     Dim showDetailsButtonLayout As New ControlLayout
>     showDetailsButtonLayout.Bind Me, ShowDetailsButton, RightAnchor
>
>     Dim deleteButtonLayout As New ControlLayout
>     deleteButtonLayout.Bind Me, DeleteButton, RightAnchor
>
>     layoutBindings.Add closeButtonLayout, _
>                        backgroundImageLayout, _
>                        itemsListLayout, _
>                        addButtonLayout, _
>                        editButtonLayout, _
>                        showDetailsButtonLayout, _
>                        deleteButtonLayout
>
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub UserForm_Resize()
>
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>
>     If Me.Width < minWidth Then Me.Width = minWidth
>     If Me.Height < minHeight Then Me.Height = minHeight
>
>     Dim layout As ControlLayout
>     For Each layout In layoutBindings
>         layout.Resize Me
>     Next
>
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
>
> End Sub
> ```

That code is reviewable as part of [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/58348/23788), and it's the client code of a class I'd like reviewed here:

> **ControlLayout** class module

There's no magic, I haven't implemented a [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf)-like automagic layout. But what I have works pretty well with what I'm using it for, I'd like to know if it could be done better:

```
Option Explicit

    Public Enum AnchorEdges
        LeftAnchor = 2 ^ 0
        TopAnchor = 2 ^ 1
        RightAnchor = 2 ^ 2
        BottomAnchor = 2 ^ 3
        AnchorAll = LeftAnchor + TopAnchor + RightAnchor + BottomAnchor
    End Enum

    Private anchors As AnchorEdges
    Private margins As SideMargins
    Private size As ControlSize

    Private formSize As ControlSize
    Private boundControl As Control

    Public Sub Bind(form As UserForm, formControl As Control, anchor As AnchorEdges)

        anchors = anchor

        formSize.Height = form.InsideHeight
        formSize.Width = form.InsideWidth

        size.Height = formControl.Height
        size.Width = formControl.Width

        If (anchor And BottomAnchor) = BottomAnchor Then
            margins.BottomMargin = formSize.Height - formControl.Top - formControl.Height
        End If

        If (anchor And LeftAnchor) = LeftAnchor Then
            margins.LeftMargin = formControl.Left
        End If

        If (anchor And RightAnchor) = RightAnchor Then
            margins.RightMargin = formSize.Width - formControl.Left - formControl.Width
        End If

        If (anchor And TopAnchor) = TopAnchor Then
            margins.TopMargin = formControl.Top
        End If

        Set boundControl = formControl

    End Sub

    Public Sub Resize(ByVal form As UserForm)

        formSize.Height = form.InsideHeight
        formSize.Width = form.InsideWidth

        layout boundControl

    End Sub

    Public Sub layout(ByVal formControl As Control)

        If (anchors And TopAnchor) = TopAnchor Then

            If (anchors And BottomAnchor) = BottomAnchor Then
                formControl.Height = formSize.Height - formControl.Top - margins.BottomMargin
            End If

        ElseIf (anchors And BottomAnchor) = BottomAnchor Then
            formControl.Top = formSize.Height - formControl.Height - margins.BottomMargin
        End If


        If (anchors And LeftAnchor) = LeftAnchor Then

            If (anchors And RightAnchor) = RightAnchor Then
                formControl.Width = formSize.Width - formControl.Left - margins.RightMargin
            End If

        ElseIf (anchors And RightAnchor) = RightAnchor Then
            formControl.Left = formSize.Width - formControl.Width - margins.RightMargin
        End If

    End Sub
```

---

I can just do this:

```
Set view = New SimpleView
view.Height = 400
view.Width = 500
view.Show
```

And get that:

[image: SimpleView 400x500]

Or this:

```
Set view = New SimpleView
view.Height = 400
view.Width = 200
view.Show
```

To get that:

[image: SimpleView 200x400]

Comment: And your question is...? Why did you put this code up for review? Do you think it can't be better (and are looking for confirmation), do you think it should be better (and are looking for alternatives)...

Comment: *"what I have works pretty well with what I'm using it for, I'd like to know if it could be done better"* - can it?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a UserForm, not an Access Form, correct?

Comment: @ckuhn203 correct, it's Excel VBA ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really like this method of declaring a bitwise enum.

```
Public Enum AnchorEdges
    LeftAnchor = 2 ^ 0
    TopAnchor = 2 ^ 1
    RightAnchor = 2 ^ 2
    BottomAnchor = 2 ^ 3
    AnchorAll = LeftAnchor + TopAnchor + RightAnchor + BottomAnchor
End Enum
```

I find it much preferable to the way I usually see it done.

> ```
> Public Enum BitWiseEnum
>     SomeValue = 1
>     SomeValue = 2
>     SomeValue = 4
>     SomeValue = 8
>  End Enum
> ```

But you don't need all of this.

```
If (anchor And BottomAnchor) = BottomAnchor Then
```

The condition can be written simply as

```
If (anchor And BottomAnchor) Then
```

I would recommend leaving a small comment alerting the unwary maintainer that it is a bitwise `And` not a logical `And` though. I don't imagine too many VBA Maintainers will understand this code at a glance.