# Run arbitrary INSERT INTO SQL Query using parameters

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

While `DoCmd.RunSQL` is all well and good for simple code, the number of times I've run into problems with unescaped apostrophes and the like was starting to nark a bit. With that in mind I crafted the below, a first attempt at a SQL wrapper for VBA which constructs and executes an arbitrary INSERT INTO query using parameters.

```vbs
'Fields should be a comma-delimited string
Public Sub InsertInto(TableName As String, Fields As String, Values As Variant)
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strParams As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strSQL As String

On Error GoTo Err_InsertInto
    'Assigns strParams value in format "[p1],[p2],[p3],...,[pN]"
    For i = 0 To UBound(Values)
        strParams = strParams & "[p" & i & "],"
    Next i
    strParams = Left(strParams, Len(strParams) - 1) 'Strip trailing comma

    'Construct SQL
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & TableName & "(" & Fields & ") " & _
             "VALUES (" & strParams & ");"
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

    'Give values to parameters
    For i = 0 To UBound(Values)
        qdf.Parameters("[p" & i & "]") = Values(i)
    Next i

    qdf.Execute

Exit_InsertInto:
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_InsertInto:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 13   'Type mismatch i.e. Values is not an array
            Values = Array(Values)
            Resume
        Case Else 'Unhandled Error
            Set qdf = Nothing 'Release QueryDef object

            'Error is unhandled here, force it to 'bubble up' to calling code
            Dim iErrNum As Long, strErrDesc As String
            iErrNum = Err.Number
            strErrDesc = Err.Description
            On Error GoTo 0
            Err.Raise iErrNum, "SQLOps.InsertInto", strErrDesc
    End Select
End Sub
```

Likely to be called in a manner similar to (this example was used as a successful test case):

```vbs
InsertInto "tblErrorLog", _
"ErrorNum,Description,User,When,Origin", _
Array(10,"Error's Description",Environ("USERNAME"),Now(),"A Ghost")
```

So far it seems to be working fine and does indeed alleviate the issues with unescaped apostrophes but I'm wondering whether this can be improved so I could use it as a sort of template for crafting similar functions for other SQL operations e.g. UPDATE SET / SELECT FROM.

Can this code be improved and are there any unforeseen bugs I should watch out for?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Looks like an interesting way of solving this problem. I hope you get some good reviews!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! While you wait for your review, you might find [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46506/41243) interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This code can't handle fields with spaces in them unless you specifically pass them pre-wrapped in square brackets. Things such as `My Field` would need to go into your parameter as `"field1, [My odd field], field3"`. So, a definite area for improvement would be to handle that corner case.

I also don't really care for the comma delimited string parameter. I feel that it would be much cleaner and nicer to pass in a string array representing the field names. So, something along the lines of this psuedo code might be a bit cleaner.

```
Dim fields As Variant
fields = Array("field1","My odd field","field3")

InsertInto "Table1", fields, values)

' ...

Public Sub InsertInto(...)
    AddBracketsToStrings fields

    '...

End Sub
```

---

The next thing I notice is these comments:

> ```
> 'Assigns strParams value in format "[p1],[p2],[p3],...,[pN]"
> ...
> 'Construct SQL
> ...
> 'Give values to parameters
> ...
> ```

The comments are nice, and add a bit of clarity to the code, but these kinds of comments indicate an opportunity to extract subroutines/functions. Each of these comments could be replaced with a well named function.

```
ConvertValuesToParameters values
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", ConstructSQL(TableName, Fields, strParams))
SetParameterValues qdf, values
```

Which brings me to the SQL Injection issue. It's never a good idea to concatenate SQL strings together. It's much better to use parameterized queries. This may require that you switch to using ADODB instead of DAO. I'm not sure. I don't know if DAO supports parameterized queries.

---

> ```
> Case 13   'Type mismatch i.e. Values is not an array
> ```

That's a good comment, but a constant value would be better.

```
Const TypeMismatchError As Long = 13

Select Case Err.Number
    Case TypeMisMatchError 
        ' ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to construct a SQL statement in VBA without concatenating _somewhere_? I can avoid it in the `VALUES(...)` part of the SQL but I'm not sure how I could avoid it with the table name and field names. Google is turning me a blank on that one. ADODB is something I might have to look into but I've never used it in the past. Great point about the field names though and I've updated my code to handle that.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea how I would address it with DAO. I almost exclusively use ADODB. And no, I suppose not. You will certainly have to concatenate values somewhere along the line. The important part is not to concat strings from the **user** into your SQL. But given what you're trying to do, I don't know how I would change it.